# How can I type the instance of an untyped class?

Tags: typescript

I am extending a class which comes from an external library and is sadly not typed.
To makes matters even more complicated, it's instantiation is done via a static method in the untyped class. The change of this as it stands is not an option. It would look something like this:

```js
class MyUntypedClass {
  constructor (context) {
    this.someAttribute = ''
    this.someOtherAttribute = ''
  }

  static createNewInstanceWithStuff () {
    // do a bunch of stuff prior to creating the instance
    const instance = new this(context)

    return instance
  }
}
```

As mentioned I then extend it and make sure to type my methods:

```js
class MyTypedClass extends MyUntypedClass {
  private myNewAttribute = ''

  constructor() {
    super({ stuff })
    this.myNewAttribute = myNewAttribute
  }

  private myNewMethod (param: string, otherParam: number): string {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

However, I must instantiate it via the static method from `MyUntypedClass`, and I end up losing the types I had written for my methods. Code looks something like this:

```js
const instance = MyTypedClass.createNewInstanceWithStuff()

const value = instance.myNewMethod('some string', 123) // if I try to check  the params or return type it is any
```

Is there anyway to type my methods whenever the instance is created from the untyped parent class?

Comment: What is `context` inside `createNewInstanceWithStuff`?  Seems like that isn't just untyped, but invalid.  Could you edit your code to be a [mre] so I can easily verify any suggested fix in an IDE?  (Also `stuff` and `myNewAttribute`... and why is `myNewMethod()` private?)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnKxom) meet your needs?  I had to change other stuff in there to make it a [mre].   If that works for you I can write up an answer.  If not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz yes! That did it :D Feel free to post this as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the static `createNewInstanceWithStuff` method of `MyTypedClass` to be of a more specific type than that of the `MyUntypedClass` but you don't want to change the runtime behavior, you can use [the `declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) to tell the compiler that.  This will have no effect on the emitted JavaScript.  It looks like this:

```
class MyTypedClass extends MyUntypedClass {
  /* ... */    
  declare static createNewInstanceWithStuff: () => MyTypedClass; // <-- declare this
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that you have to use a [function-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) [field annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) instead of a [method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#methods), because the `declare` property modifier is not currently supported for methods (see [microsoft/TypeScript#38008](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38008) for the relevant feature request).

Now it should work as expected:

```
const instance = MyTypedClass.createNewInstanceWithStuff();
// const instance: MyTypedClass
const value = instance.myNewMethod('some string', 123) 
// const value: string;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#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-0BnGBIwwIFyECwWolkOSpDuoIqTyGCLxKKgzgO5uKlsH1rqUkagvaXtIfv7lytyhHHrHED7zPuZJAnHpA+uspjRTjCaT-nC6zYJ38uYAjAAmADMtlXU37R5PNaPscXpAA)